# Google map is not working in Angular and giving an error of InvalidKeyMapError

Tags: angular, agm

I just installed `agm/core` and related stuff to use maps using these commands

```
npm install @agm/core --save
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

And then i imported `AgmCoreModule` like this in my `module.ts`

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

imports : [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'my api key',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
]
```

And inside of my component i just used `map` like this

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

But i am getting this error

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
```

I don't know why this error is occurring. Can any one let me know?

Comment: This error usually states, that the apiKey is not correct.. Double check that. I also heard, that it could occur if the js gets included twice.

Comment: No i double checked this issue. I recently generated a new apiKey and i just installed `agm/core` library in my project and included in my just one module also with api key.